# Setting up nginx via puppet

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to use puppet to set up nginx. I found this module:

https://github.com/example42/puppet-nginx

I am using Vagrant, which I believe includes all the modules in the "modules" directory. I have added puppet-nginx into that directory.

I have a manifest file which has:

```
class { "nginx": }
```

However, that doesn't seem to work.

```
Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class nginx at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:50 on node vagrant-ubuntu-raring-64
```

Any idea why this isn't working? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you configured Vagrant properly:

- provisioning with Puppet must be enabled
- you can try to set `module_path` explicitly
- try to rename directory `puppet-nginx` to `nginx` (or create symlink)

Comment: for some reason, renaming the directory to nginx did the job! thanks! Any idea why tho?

Comment: This is because when you specify class `nginx` Puppet tries to find this class inside file `$MODULEDIR`/nginx/manifests/init.pp`

Answer (score 0):

In your Vagrant directory issue

```
puppet module install --force "example42/nginx" --target-dir ./puppet/modules
```

Make sure your Vagrantfile contains the following:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.module_path = 'puppet/modules'
end
```